# EaselJS: Changing Shape Color on De-select

Tags: shapes, addeventlistener, easeljs

(Note: Just to clarify, by "de-select" I mean selecting other shape than the currently selected one, thereby de-selecting the initially selected shape)

Just to elaborate a bit more, I got a series of shapes on a canvas. Any shape I click on changes its color from, say, red to white. But then, there can only be ONE white-colored shape at any given time. That means, if I click on shape-A first then shape-B, shape-A's color must change from white back to red the moment I click on shape-B.

Adding a "click" event listener to every shape was a no-brainer. But, I am at a loss as to how to point back to the previous shape object so that I can restore its original color.

Any help will be much appreciated!

---

Update: Upon further research, I'm starting to think that my objective boils down to this - Finding a way to point to any Shape object NOT through some event listener but via a method call by passing the object's ID. However, I just checked the Shape class methods [here](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Shape.html) but didn't see anything that might be useful. Could I be missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I hope I understood you correctly)
Your "issue" is more of a program-flow issue that is not really specific to a easeljs or any ObjectType.

All you have to do is set a (global) reference to the clicked object inside the click-listener, i'd call it `window.lastClickedShape` or something similar. And whenever a shape is clicked you check if `lastClickedShape != null` and reset the color for that object.

Comment: olsn - You're definitely right and your answer helped me realize I was neglecting something so obvious. Thanks!